# Generic plain text from binary file extracting library

Tags: java, text-extraction

I am after a general purpose unspecialised plain text file extractor.

Firstly before people shout look at Apache Tika - my response is that it only supports some popular binary file formats like Office, BMPs etc.

Back to the problem - Many binary files have text strings embedded in them, which i would like to extract without the binary byte noise. THis would mean it could find simple text string sequences in exes and so on with the result only holding ascii words. I tried googling but could not find anything that did this. My basic idea is if a file is not handled by TIKA this simple binary file handler would try its best to find these text strings.

Comment: What is wrong with `string`?  http://linux.die.net/man/1/strings

Comment: Sorry im in java and i want to stay in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing my code class to solve my problem.

Important features/considerations.

- Only accepts cr, nl, tab, space - char127 -

  - Ignores all characters that are no ascii
  - bad luck if file includes unicode.
- ignores character sequences that are leass than a few chars (configurable).

  - this means that bytes that are a single letter surrounded by other non ASCII values are ignored.
- a space is inserted between character sequences

  - this means that one string, some bytes and then other string appears in the result as two words separated by a string rather than a single long word.

Answer (score 0):

The following code filters non printable ASCII character.

```
package sandbox;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author yan-cheng.cheok
 */
public class Main {

    // Returns the contents of the file in a byte array.
    public static byte[] getBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

        // Get the size of the file
        long length = file.length();

        // You cannot create an array using a long type.
        // It needs to be an int type.
        // Before converting to an int type, check
        // to ensure that file is not larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE.
        if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            // File is too large
        }

        // Create the byte array to hold the data
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];

        // Read in the bytes
        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (offset < bytes.length
               && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
            offset += numRead;
        }

        // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
        if (offset < bytes.length) {
            throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());
        }

        // Close the input stream and return bytes
        is.close();
        return bytes;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File f = new File("c:\\jstock.exe");
        byte[] bs = getBytesFromFile(f);
        List<Byte> list = new ArrayList<Byte>();
        for (byte b : bs) {
            if (b >= 0) {
                // Printable ASCII code.
                list.add(b);
            }
        }

        byte[] output = new byte[list.size()];
        for (int i = 0, size = list.size(); i < size; i++) {
            output[i] = list.get(i);
        }
        System.out.println(new String(output));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is not really useful because it would extract every single letter, digit inside a binary file even when they are not clear that they are not part of a text string.

Comment: if a binary file had bytes a letter, some more bytes another letter and so on, your code would give me letter all squished up together w/out any spacers.